# Hide/display column (ObjectListView)?

Tags: c#, objectlistview

I am using ObjectListView in C# trying to hide/show a column ("colRating") in an ObjectListView called "cars". In the docs there is this code snippet:

```
this.olvColumn2.IsVisible = false;
this.olv1.RebuildColumns();
```

Problem is that i can´t use "this" because i want to change another listView. So i tried this:

```
cars.colRating.IsVisible = false;
```

It doesn´t work. Tried using:

```
cars.AllColumns["colRating"].IsVisble = false;
```

Any help appriciated!

[UPDATE]
This is solved! For some reason i could not access the columns in code. But after deleting the columns and adding them again i could access the actual column name in code.

Comment: Setting `IsVisible` to `true` will not hide the column. You need to set it to `false`

Comment: @pstrds not the issue...but have edited my original post.

Comment: You can just access colRating.IsVisible from code. Its an instance variable created by the designer. No need for "this." or "cars.".

Comment: @Rev1.0 i couldn´t...something happened. But after i deleted the columns and added them again...i suddenly could access colRating though code.